# Shrink wrapping a column to the width of a grid of images

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have the following site.

```
#left_column {
width: 200px;
}

<div id="left_column">
/* some content */
</div>

<div id="right_column">
/* A bunch of 100px width photos that are being floated */
</div>
```

As the code implies, the site is composed of a left column and a right column. The left column is 200 pixels wide. The right column will hold a bunch of images. Depending on the width of a person's screen, the right column may fit 7 images per row, or 10, or more. Moreover, there will almost always be space left over to the right of each row (because the screen's width is not a multiple of 100).

I want the right_column to shrink wrap around the images so that it's width does not go beyond the right border of the right-most image. In other words, I want right_column's width to be equal to the sum of all the widths of the images that can fit on each row.

Comment: I think you will need to use javascript. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, I came up with this: http://jsbin.com/ijedej/4/edit

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var column_width = Math.floor(($("#body").innerWidth()-$("#left_column").width())/100)*100;
  $("#right_column").css("width", column_width);
});
```

So this works out how much space is available (`$("#body").innerWidth()`), subtracts the width of the left column, divides that by 100, floors it to get an integer then multiplies it by 100 to get the new width.

You can probably do it without jQuery, but that's not something I'm great at.

Comment: Hey Mike, did you find a solution?